# Can a paper crease be a sirtut?

Tags: tefilin, sefer-torah, safrus, mezuzah

When writing books of Tanakh, we need a *sirtut*, a horizontal line that helps align the text. Indeed, it is forbidden to write any three words of a verse in [*k'tav Ashurit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ktav_Ashuri) without a *sirtut*. See, for example, [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 284:1–2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.284.2):

> ‮כל כתבי הקודש אין כותבין בלא שרטוט אפילו כתובים על הנייר. אסור לכתוב ג׳ תיבות מפסוק בלא שרטוט אם הוא כתב אשורית.
>
> All *kitvei hakodesh* must be written with a *sirtut*, even when written on paper. It is forbidden to write three words from a verse without a *sirtut* if one is writing in *k'tav Ashurit*.

Usually, as far as I know, a *sirtut* is made using a [scratch awl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_awl) (eg. see an online store [here](https://merkazhasofrim.com/sirtut-scoring-tool.html)). I also know that one should not make a *sirtut* using something that will leave a coloured mark. See, for example, [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 271:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.271.5?lang=bi):

> ‮ולא ישרטט בעופרת וכיוצא בו שצובע.
>
> He should not line [the parchment] with lead or something like it because it colors [the parchment].

What are the minimum requirements for making a *sirtut*? Does creasing the paper count as a *sirtut*, or does it need an external implement? Are there other requirements besides not to leave a coloured mark on the paper/parchment?

Comment: I don't know if you know this background, but this is actually a pretty controversial topic recently in stam. Certain modern producers made sirtut that doesn't retain its groove but retained the discoloration and it made a big hubbub. So there's a fair amount of modern literature, but often written such all the people who supported/opposed the manufacturers happened to think it was fine/pasul, if you get my drift. I'm trying to describe this without taking a position. It's a hard sugya to bring strong proofs in because there's so little material to work with.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't aware of this. I'd be happy to read literature on both sides just to get an idea, if you have some samples.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the rules for a kosher sefer Torah are stricter than the rules for not writing a verse without sirtut in middle of a letter, etc. See Haskamos by R' Aryeh Malkiel Kotler, who draws a line in pen under the verses he quotes.

Comment: @N.T. *arguably stricter. Certainly not less strict

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_1.156 folding gittin quoted in pitchei teshuva https://www.sefaria.org/Pithei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.271.13

Comment: @DoubleAA Looks like an answer. Are there חולקים that you know of?

Comment: I don't feel qualified to say for sure. It's a really opaque sugya. This is from R' Ratzabi (it includes the question from R' Gross), probably the most preeminent Shami-Temani posek today http://www.maharitz.com/hordot/shirtut.pdf arguing for needing a groove. R' Timor who is a world expert in old sefardi stam recently published an extensive article in the [Otzar journal #52](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=31425&start=280) rebutting some of those claims and analyzing all the sources. My gut says R' Timor is right but at the same time the clear overwhelming minhag is to make a groo

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for those. That's a lot to sink my teeth into for now (and for a while)!